# Adding LINQ to SQL (dbml) class reference in .cs file in app code

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, dbml

I have created a Linq(dbml) class wherein i have certain tables, i have saved the class file

Now i want to reference that class in .cs file in App_Code. But it does not shows me in the Intellisense. But i am able to use the same class in .aspx.cs pages.

Below is the name of my dbml file:

```
GlobalDatabase.dbml
```

Below is the reference i use in .aspx.cs file:

```
GlobalDatabaseDataContext context = new GlobalDatabaseDataContext();
```

Can anyone tell me how can i refer the same in .cs in App_Code.

Comment: Does your DBML have a namespace set?

Comment: yes, i had forgot to use the namespace in the .cs file, anyways very thanks for your help.